# Plotting 3D piecewise function with distinct colors

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I want to draw the following picture in Mathematica as shown below with distinct color for each section.

[image]

Comment: Well, did you try anything and, if yes, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I used this code:
Plot3D[-1/4 x^3, {x, -20, 20}, {y, 0, 30}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x}, 
   Piecewise[{{Red, -20 <= x < -10}, {Orange, -10 <= x < 0}, {Yellow, 
      0 <= x <= 20}}]], PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `MeshShading`:

```
Plot3D[
 -(x - 12.5)^3,
 {x, 0, 25},
 {y, 0, 20},
 MeshShading -> {Table[Hue[x], {x, 0, 1, 1/16}]}
 ]
```

The `Table` part generates sixteen different colors from the `Hue` color function. I did this because the image in this case had sixteen rows. If there are more rows than colors the colors will be reused cyclically.

[image: Mesh shading]

Comment: Thanks you. and about dotted grid lines in background?

Comment: @MathMan I was away, it seems Mr.Wizard solved it in the meantime :)

Answer (score 6):

Building on Pickett's answer with a few more Options:

```
pl = Plot3D[-(x - 12.5)^3, {x, 0, 25}, {y, 0, 20}, 
 MeshShading -> {Table[Hue[x], {x, 0, 1, 1/16}]},
 BoxRatios -> 1, 
 Boxed -> False,
 FaceGrids -> {{0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
 FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Thick, Gray, Dotted]
]
```

[image]

It's not perfect but hopefully it points you in a useful direction.

---

An example for the legend was requested.  One can use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html) to place a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html) (or other) object in a 3D plot.  As a rough illustration:

```
rec = Graphics[{Green, EdgeForm[Thick], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {50, 20}]}, 
   ImageSize -> {50, 20}, PlotRangePadding -> 0];

lg = Framed[Row[{rec, Style["S", 18]}]];

Show[pl, Epilog -> Inset[lg, Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I copied the wrong code for that particular graphic.  Now corrected.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: and about the Legend?

Comment: @MathMan Which version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 7

Comment: @MathMan See update.